# Attraction of events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, examples-counterexamples

I don't know if the next statement is true or false:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $A,B$ and $C$ be events in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $P(A)>0$. If $P(B|A)>P(B)$ and $P(C|A)>P(C)$, then $P(B\cap C|A)\geq P(B\cap C)$.

Neither I haven't been able to prove it, nor I haven't been able to find a counterexample. Can anyone help to determine the truth or falsity of the statement please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case.

Say we uniformly randomly pick an integer from $[1,19]$. Then it has probability $\frac{10}{19}$ to be odd, $\frac8{19}$ to be prime and $\frac7{19}$ to be an odd prime. If I now tell you that it’s in $[1,9]$, the probability that it’s odd increases to $\frac59$ and the probability that it’s prime increases to $\frac49$, but the probability that it’s an odd prime decreases to $\frac39$.

Comment: thank you, how did you arrive at such a counterexample?

Comment: @RataMágica: I realized that a counterexample would need to have relatively large $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ but relatively small $A\cap B\cap C$, and this seemed to fit the bill because both the first ten numbers and the next ten numbers contain $4$ primes, but in one of them one of the primes is even; then I just had to choose the exact bounds such that the lower part would have a greater share of the odd numbers despite having a smaller share of the odd primes. It would have been easier to construct some artificial example on a smaller set, but I wanted to provide a “mathematical” example :-)